# I'm getting spam when I load //pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js

Tags: adsense, spam

When I load `<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>`, images on my page get replaced with spam ads of all kinds.

I'm testing bare bones in a guest instance of chrome on my pc.

This is the original code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="/images/ads/mm-mug-wide.jpg" />
    </body>
</html>
```

These are screen shots of the network log with and without the adsense javascript. By the time I killed it, the network log with adsense showed 455 requests over 35 minutes.

- With Adsense Javascript: https://18103791804392046531.googlegroups.com/attach/1841b7c6b6b0b5/adsense-network-log-with-adsense.jpg?part=0.3&view=1&vt=ANaJVrFCJMUV-pol5F7XFKcts8bc50qnvFbazg6PVlZXCOCj7PSJXGBJQkoZaU9AzQcs7xh0VS03Q8-pCS9c9iErGlhHCP3mkSWUMeMumfeQPkKkWpanUDU
- Without Adsense Javascript: https://18103791804392046531.googlegroups.com/attach/1841b7c6b6b0b5/adsense-network-log-without-adsense.jpg?part=0.2&view=1&vt=ANaJVrHGcOCztReWJmK09Yr0YpkouhCZwxFzmmjfRfk2wyB0Rr9vb30Hl7SkanKF06LcCCxDvElQx4tB_ZQYRxB-96zOY8gXEp_IjL6q6pOzlsSuA4-nQZ8

UPDATE:
It only seems to do it if the word 'ad' or 'ads' ('header' was not a match) appear in the src. If the class is 'ad', it starts loading the spam resources but does not replace the image or continue on indefinitely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DNS on my router had been altered to point to a malicious DNS that was rerouting things such as google adsense.

Answer (score -2):

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<script>
  (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
    google_ad_client: "ca-pub-6483687610557857",
    enable_page_level_ads: true
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Code only answers arent encouraged as they dont provide much information for future readers please provide some explanation to what you have written